# convert, parentheses, -mosaic and order

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

When I try to combine two images using `-mosaic`, I seem to have two choices:

```
$ convert logo: rose: -mosaic result.png
$ convert -mosaic logo: rose: result.png
```

Both result in the same image. This is not true anymore, if I use parentheses:

```
$ convert logo: \( rose: \) -mosaic result.png
```

still yields the same output image, but the next one

```
$ convert -mosaic logo: \( rose: \) result.png
```

has a quite different result.

Can somebody explain why the last result is different? Is this a bug in `convert` or another concept in ImageMagick I have failed to grasp yet?

I'm using ImageMagick 6.8.6-2 (as packaged by Arch Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found out about why it works this way. However, despite the enormous amount of documentation available, ImageMagick still seems like an arcane science, because of the diverse compatibility layers woven in.

After reading http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#cmdline, i think I can summarize the following:

1. ImageMagick 6.x has a completely new syntax, in which it doesn't make sense to have any operator in front of the first image.
2. ImageMagick 6.x tries to emulate the syntax of the older 5.x versions to some degree ("simple 5.x operations like `convert [operator] [input-image] [output-image]` should still be possible.")
3. If I understand correctly, the parentheses were not part of 5.x.
4. So it would be not too far fetched to conclude that the existence of parentheses on the command line disables the compatibility mode somehow, which would explain the behaviour observed.

If anyone reading this has similar problems with the syntax of convert to mine, I recommend reading the link above and not stop studying it until you have completely understood the concept of image lists, image operators and image sequence operators. It is not too complicated, but if you just use trial & error, you will, like me, have a VERY hard time understanding the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses create a sub-process, or [image stack](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#stack), which allows additional image processing to be isolated from the parent process.

```
$ convert logo: rose: -mosaic result.png
```

[image]

```
$ convert logo: \( rose: -negate -resize 200% \) -mosaic result.png
```

[image]

Sequence of commands can be important, as mosaic is expecting layers to join. The following commands are identical, as the -mosaic command is ignored & no commands are executed on any sub-process.

```
$ convert logo: rose: result.png
$ convert logo: \( rose: \) result.png
$ convert -mosaic logo: \( rose: \) result.png
```

Comment: I already knew about the purpose of the parentheses. This however does not answer my »why« question concerning the difference between the invocations.